# Selenium multple xpaths how to select a specific xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium to select an xpath based on the date but there are two separate dates in the html both that start with td.  How do I specify which date to select?  Do I place a [2] at the end of the search text?

The line looks like this

```
List<WebElement> li2 = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "')]/preceding::*5[]"
```

so should I do this

```
List<WebElement> li2 = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "'[2])]/preceding::*5[]"
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? It is hard to answer this question because we don't know what the HTML looks like. If the list of `WebElement` objects change, the bottom solution might work intermittently. If each entry has a unique attribute, like `id`, you may want to `and` attributes together in the predicate `"//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "') and id='someID']"`

Comment: Here is the html im working with https://gist.github.com/kayfay/bb0a72d8727fca739b93f86acebf579b  there is a second date within the html document that I need to access but the selenium code is finding the first one.  All the tag contains is the td and the date.

Comment: I'm not sure what the code would look like if I were to select the second occurrence if someone would be able to show me an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> li2 = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "')]"))
```

you are using list do you can get the element get (list index starts from 0 )

```
 WebElement li = li2.get(4)
```

or

you can get 5th result of xpath by enclosing the xpath locator with brackets and calling [5]  ( here index starts from 1 )

```
 WebElement li = driver.findElements(by.xpath("(//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "')])[5]"))
```

If you want to get 5th sibling then don't enclose it with bracket  , this will say get the 5th td tag that is a sibling and contains the date

```
    WebElement li = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "')][5]"))
```

Comment: This isn't the part of the statement I needed help with.  The preceding 5 is to select the first element in a table that's clickable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question.

```
List<WebElement> li2 = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + date " "')]/preceding::*5[1]"
```

Would be how to index this particular xpath.